# Get child count of grid view after setting adapter

Tags: android

I have the following code:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    static final String[] transacciones = new String[] {
        "Retiro", "Depósito", "Pago", "Administrativas"
    };

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_opciones, container, false);
        GridView gridViewOpciones = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridViewOpciones);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                transacciones);
        gridViewOpciones.setAdapter(adapter);

        for (int i=0; i<gridViewOpciones.getChildCount(); i++) {
            // Get view and then add a click listener
        }
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

I want to get every view inside the grid view and set a click listener to each one.

After debugging I notice my getChildCount method returns 0 despite the fact that my activity is rendering the grid view correctly (with all four options).

Why doesn't getChildCount method returns 4 as I expected to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set OnClickListener for every item in your gridview use this code

```
gridViewOpciones.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {

            String str= (String) gridViewOpciones.getItemAtPosition(position);
            // do whatever you need with string

        }


    });
```